# Save very large documents into Filenet with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filenet-panagon, filenet-idm

I am trying to save a very large document (8GB) into Filenet with vb.net.

The error i get from the console is:

CSMr: Open objects closed due to network error

[E] Specific Exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80041A0D): Commit new
>   document fa iled.    at IDMObjects.IFnDocumentDual.SaveNew(Object
>   Files, Object SaveNewOptions)

My code for this action is:

```
Dim objFnDoc As IDMObjects.Document

objFnDoc = FnLib.CreateObject(IDMObjects.idmObjectType.idmObjTypeDocument, modAppConfigSettings.ClassName)

objFnDoc.SaveNew(NewFileLocation,IDMObjects.idmSaveNewOptions.idmDocSaveNewKeep)

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objFnDoc)
```

Note that for smaller documents it work fine.
I search a lot for an possible cause and i didn't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is just network timeout issue, check documentation for improve filenet upload
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.performance.doc/p8ppt135.htm

also you can change advanced filenet parameters to increase timeouts.